# Jasmine/Karma unit testing AngularJS service: how to mock "import"

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

We have a Karma/Jasmine unit tests set up for a legacy AngularJS (v1) app (nowadays compiled with Webpack). We're trying to build unit tests for a service that uses regular Angular injections BUT also an `import` statement. Something like this:

```
import myMember from 'my-module';

(function () {
  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .service('myService', myService);

  myService.$inject = ['$window', 'anotherService'];

  function myService($window, anotherService) {
    ...
  }
})();
```

The `import` part poses a challenge because I need to mock `myMember` from the imported module.

<s>First I tried testing like before, but, naturally, when I try to access `myMember` in any way, I get an error: **"myMember is not defined"**</s>

Then I tried inserting a similar `import` statement at the beginning of the unit test file. However: **"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"**

Can't seem to wrap my head around this issue. Anyone got a hint how to move forward?

**EDIT:** The project has a complicated structure and `import` **started working** when the test file was located deeper in the directory structure. Maybe something related to file running order. Dunno. Anyways, **mocking** still remains a challenge.